# Java Inheritance and Method Dispatch

Tags: java, methods, dynamic, static, overloading

Given this Java code:

```
class A {
public void foo (Object o) { System.out.println("A"); }
}

class B {
public void foo (String o) { System.out.println("B"); }
}

class C extends A {
public void foo (String s) { System.out.println("C"); }
}

class D extends B {
public void foo (Object o) { System.out.println("D"); }
}

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = new C(); a.foo("Java"); 
  C c = new C(); c.foo("Java"); 
  B b = new D(); b.foo("Java"); 
  D d = new D(); d.foo("Java");
  } 
}
```

why is the result `ACBB`?
I wil try to explain what I think, and I would appreciate if someone lets me know where my gap is.

So what I thought with the first two calls is:

- `a` has static type `A`, but dynamic type `C` so Java should dispatch the method call dynamically and call `foo()` in C printing "C".
- `c` has static and dynamic type `C`, so now since we inherit from A, it has to choose the most specific method, which is `public void foo(String s)` and thus printing "C"
- `b` has static type `B` but dynamic type `D` so also in this case it should dynamically dispatch and call `foo()` in `D` printing "D".
- `d` has static and dynamic type `D`, so now since we inherit from B, it has to choose the most specific method, which is `public void foo(String o)` and thus printing "B"

What is wrong in this explanation I've given here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo(Object)` doesn't *override* `foo (String)` but *overloads* it. Hence `D` has 2 methods and since the most specific one will be used it will be `foo(String)` when you pass a string parameter.

From [JLS 15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) (emphasis by me):

> This step uses the name of the method and the argument expressions to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable, that is, declarations that can be correctly invoked on the given arguments.
>
> There may be more than one such method, in which case the *most specific one* is chosen.

Comment: I played around with it, and I understood what you mean. 
So whenever I have `A a = new C()` and call `a.foo("Hello")` I can be sure that only the static type method will be resolved right? Because dispatch happens only if we override the method in C. Is this statement correct?

Comment: @DevX10 I'd say it that way: dispatch (how I understand it) will happen in any case and 2 times: 1) at compile time when the compiler selects the best matching method signature (in case of calling `foo("Java")` on a variable of type `A` that will be `foo(Object)` since that's the only visible method signature) and 2) at runtime where the JVM selects the appropriate implementation of that signature based on the actual type of the object the method is called on (i.e. should `C` override `foo(Object)` the overriding version would be called in your example).

Answer (score 0):

`A a = new C(); a.foo("Java");` calls `foo(String)` method from `a` which is a `A`
`C c = new C(); c.foo("Java");` calls `foo(String)` method from `c` which is a `C`
`B b = new D(); b.foo("Java");` calls `foo(String)` method from `b` which is a  `B`
`D d = new D(); d.foo("Java");` calls `foo(String)` method from `d` which **only exists on `B`** (`D` contains `foo(Object)`)